# Treatment of Map manipulation in parallel programming

Tags: go

Do I have to treat the mentioned 2 procedures with a mutex, if several threads can access these procedures at the same time?
The **AddToMap** function adds a new row with a new key, and the **ModifyMap** only changes the value for an already existing key.

```
func AddToMap(a TWorkerMsg) { // new a.key  value
    mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()

    gMap[a.key] = a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user
    cnt := len(gMap)
    fmt.Println("AddToMap " + fmt.Sprint(cnt) + " gMap[" + a.key + "]=" + a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user)
}

func ModifyMap(a TWorkerMsg) { // a.key is exist ( but  a.ip changed) 
    mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()

    gMap[a.key] = a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user
    cnt := len(gMap)
    fmt.Println("ModifyMap " + fmt.Sprint(cnt) + " gMap[" + a.key + "]=" + a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user)
}
```

I tried to test it even without the mutex, there was no problem, but I don't know if it is necessary there.

Answer (score 3):

Maps are not thread safe so you need to use mutex. I suggest you to use methods and a  struct of your map and a mutex.

```
type gMapObj struct {
    gMap map[string]string
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

func (mo *gMapObj) Init() {
    mo.gMap = make(map[string]string)
}

func (mo *gMapObj) AddToMap(a TWorkerMsg) { // new a.key  value
    mo.mu.Lock()
    defer mo.mu.Unlock()

    mo.gMap[a.key] = a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user
    cnt := len(mo.gMap)
    fmt.Println("AddToMap " + fmt.Sprint(cnt) + " gMap[" + a.key + "]=" + a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user)
}

func (mo *gMapObj) ModifyMap(a TWorkerMsg) { // a.key is exist ( but  a.ip changed)
    mo.mu.Lock()
    defer mo.mu.Unlock()

    mo.gMap[a.key] = a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user
    cnt := len(mo.gMap)
    fmt.Println("ModifyMap " + fmt.Sprint(cnt) + " gMap[" + a.key + "]=" + a.t1 + "(" + a.ip + ")" + a.user)
}

func main() {
    gMap := gMapObj{}
    gMap.Init()
    gMap.AddToMap(a)
    gMap.ModifyMap(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to synchronize concurrent read/write access to maps using *the same mutex instance*. So what you are trying to do is correct, but the code is not.

Assuming `gMap` is a global map, you need a global mutex to serialize access to it:

```
var gMapMutex sync.Mutex

func AddToMap(a TWorkerMsg) { 
   gMapMutex.Lock()
   defer gMapMutex.Unlock()
   ...
}

func ModifyMap(a TWorkerMsg) { 
    mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()
    ...
}
```